# How to make contract transactions with Web3.py

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, dapps, web3.py

I am getting error while deploying smart contracts with web3.py. The error says "web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode".
I have included the solidity contract along with web3.py code and error logs.
Am i doing the correct way or there is some other issues?
Thanks in advance.

[image: web3.py code to interact with smart contract]
[image: solidity contract]
[image: error message]

Answer (score 1):

It's possible your blockchain doesn't support the Shanghai update. Since solidity v 0.8.20, the compiler implements the new opcode PUSH0, which your blockchain might think it's invalid.

So, change the solidity version from:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
```

to:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.8.20;
```

Comment: i changed to version and got the following error "web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert". Thanks.